# Spring Boot @Scheduled fixedDelay stop working after some uncertain time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am using @scheduled fixeddelay on my spring boot application for fetching record from different servers.
So scheduler works fine sometime for 2 days but sometime its stop working after 3 or 4 hour.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void testThread1() {

System.out.println("Scheduler is working----------------------------------------");
    String startTime = null;
    ResponseModel mResponseModel = mViewService.viewServerService("isScheduled", -1);
    if (mResponseModel != null) {
        if (mResponseModel.getStatus() == 1) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<ServerModel> serverDataList = (ArrayList<ServerModel>) mResponseModel.getMyObjectList();

            if (serverDataList.size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < serverDataList.size(); i++) {
                    ServerModel mServerModel = serverDataList.get(i);
                    if (mServerModel.getDataRequest() == 1) {
                        startTime = getLastRecordTimeDB(mServerModel);
                        String api_url = "API_URL";

                        mSingleTransitReq.request(api_url, _url, mServerModel);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("No Data");
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error = " + mResponseModel.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Getting null while requesting for server into database ");
    }

}
```

Need help on this.

Comment: Does it fail with any of the error data that you are printing?

Comment: It gives no error that is the problem.

Comment: Can you put log statements in the first and last line of the method? Something like *start* and *end*. This way you can see if your application gets stuck in one of the scheduled calls (which would explain why there is no further call).

Comment: @cmoetzing there is print on starting of scheduler now you can see my edited post.

Comment: @NikhilSharma Have you configured logging? Other components will use the log system, not `System.out`. Is the last thing you see `Scheduler is working----------------------------------------` followed by `No Data` for example?

Comment: @cmoetzing i haven't configured logging on above method but other method which is called by this scheduler have logging.

Comment: @cmoetzing when ever scheduler run its give me  Scheduler is working---------------------------------------- on server log.